# Fixed header with scrolling content? And minor css question

Tags: html, css

How can I make the header fixed and the content scroll "under" the header? Also how can I get the CSS Play button to be above the line and look decent?

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>lingo records</title>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png">
    <link rel="author" href="http://forksforoatmeal.com">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/lingo.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/js/lingo.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1 class="header">lingo records</h1>
        <ul id="navigation">
            <li><a href="#home">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="#samples">samples</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="music_player">
            <span id="pp"></span>
            <span id="song"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="footer">
        &copy; 2010 lingo records. <a href="http://forksforoatmeal.com">Josh Brown</a>
    </div>
    </body> 
    </html>
```

lingo.css:

```
/* Yahoo Style Reset Code licensed under the BSD License: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/license.html version: 2.8.1 */
html{color:#FFF;}body,div,dl,dt,dd,ul,ol,li,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,pre,code,form,fieldset,legend,input,button,textarea,p,blockquote,th,td{margin:0;padding:0;}table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}fieldset,img{border:0;}address,caption,cite,code,dfn,em,strong,th,var,optgroup{font-style:inherit;font-weight:inherit;}del,ins{text-decoration:none;}li{list-style:none;}caption,th{text-align:left;}h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{font-size:100%;font-weight:normal;}q:before,q:after{content:'';}abbr,acronym{border:0;font-variant:normal;}sup{vertical-align:baseline;}sub{vertical-align:baseline;}legend{color:#000;}input,button,textarea,select,optgroup,option{font-family:inherit;font-size:inherit;font-style:inherit;font-weight:inherit;}input,button,textarea,select{*font-size:100%;}


body {
/*  background-color: #63B7D4;*/
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 30px;
    font-family: 'Philosopher', sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #4F5155;
}

a {
    color: #475152;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-weight: normal;
}


h1.header {
    font-family: 'Philosopher', sans-serif;
    font-size: 70px;
    letter-spacing: -4px;
}

#header {
    position: static;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D0D0D0;
}

#header #navigation a {
    font-family: 'Philosopher', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul#navigation > li {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

#header #navigation a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#header #navigation a:last-child {
    margin-right: 0px;
}

#content {
    margin-top: 60px;
    font-size: 20px;
}


#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
}


/* Music Player */
#music_player {
    float:right;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    width: 250px;
}

.play {
    display:block;
    width:0;
    height:0;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width: 8px 0px 8px 16px;
    border-color:transparent transparent transparent #4F5155;

}
.pause{
    display:block;
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    border-left:32px double #4F5155;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: Philosopher;
    src: url(/assets/fonts/Philosopher.otf);
    font-weight:400;
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!
-Josh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `position: fixed` for it to stay in place as the user scrolls, although you'd probably need to apply a (semi-transparent) background for the header contents to be visible when the user scrolls. The styles you need to add are:

```
#header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%; /* Or whatever width you need it to be */
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7); /* Use semi-transparent png for IE support */
  top: 10px;
}

#content {
  margin-top: 160px; /* To push content off the top of the page */
}
```

As for the song player, you need to provide either a link to the page you are working on, or some sort of sample, as without the Javascript it is impossible to see what sort of markup is generated and what style is necessary for it to 'look decent'.

**Edit:** About that music player button... The method you're using looks to me to be a bit of a hack. I mean, you have to be *really* desperate to need to use `border` to create the play triangle, right? You're probably better off just using `background-image` instead, with something like

```
#pp {
  background: url('path/to/image.png') no-repeat scroll left top;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

for the play button.

Comment: When I do that the #content and #header are jumbled together though. Any suggestions?

Comment: This is a mockup, the song player will just display a css generated play/pause (.play/.pause) in #pp and the javascript will place the current song into the #song.

Comment: @Josh: I'd noticed that. However, your `id` for the play button is `pp`, while the styles you applied for the play button were for something with the class `play`, so I assumed the play button were to be added with js.

Comment: @Yi Jiang: The pp is so I can just change the class of it wether the jPlayer is playing or paused with a callback from jPlayer. Thanks